# What is ".htaccess" and what are the best ways of preventing the website from hacking?

Tags: security, .htaccess

I am a newbie in security and all that type of stuff. While studying of security and heard of ".htaccess" alot but couldn't get it how it used and in what language it's script is written. Next, I also want to know the **BEST** ways of preventing our website from hacking? Can you give me some examples of websites never hacked? or have a very strong security?

Comment: Form wiki `A .htaccess (hypertext access) file is a directory-level configuration file supported by several web servers, that allows for decentralized management of web server configuration. They are placed inside the web tree, and are able to override a subset of the server's global configuration for the directory that they are in, and all sub-directories`

Comment: You didn't gave the answer of my questionS :) but +1 for your comment! :

Comment: [how to prevent website from hacking](http://www.google.com.pk/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&pq=what%20is%20htaccess&cp=29&gs_id=1py&xhr=t&q=How%20to%20prevent%20website%20from%20hacking&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=How+to+prevent+website+from+h&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=51f4fbb59bb9038b&biw=1366&bih=595)

Comment: .htaccess and .htpasswd examples: http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

Comment: Even stackoverflow tag wiki has the answer for the first question: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info

Comment: @user1615903 my real question about .htaccess is in what script it is written but no one's giving the right answer :(

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui you want to know that How to use htaccess?

Comment: I gave the link.You can see it in detail now :) Goodluck Bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see how to use htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/) 
.htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. When a .htaccess file is placed in a directory which is in turn 'loaded via the Apache Web Server', then the .htaccess file is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server software. These .htaccess files can be used to alter the configuration of the Apache Web Server software to enable/disable additional functionality and features that the Apache Web Server software has to offer. These facilities include basic redirect functionality, for instance if a 404 file not found error occurs, or for more advanced functions such as content password protection or image hot link prevention. 
[Here you can get a very easy and detailed way to understand and use htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) 
 *On OP's insist* **Some best ways** 
**1)** *Use encryption*

To go along with storing your data on your hard drive as well as an external drive, make sure to encrypt it! This way if a hacker does get access to your computer, you get to put up a security gate and make everything hard to access. Try TrueCrypt when starting to encrypt your data.

**2)** *Install Firewall and Anti-Virus Software*

Firewalls forbid outside threats like hackers and viruses from being able to access your system. Now a days most computers already have anti-virus software on them from the beginning, but be sure to check that it is not outdated (or that you even have one) and to make sure it runs scans frequently.

**3)** *Keep software up to date* 
You may not think your site has anything worth being hacked for, but websites are compromised all the time. The majority of security breaches are not to steal your data or deface your website, but instead attempts to use your server as an email relay for spam, or to setup a temporary web server, normally to serve files of an illegal nature. Hacking is regularly performed by automated scripts written to scour the Internet in an attempt to exploit known security issues in software. Here are our top 10 tips to help keep you and your site safe online:
Advertisement
1. Keep software up to date

It may seem obvious, but ensuring you keep all software up to date is vital in keeping your site secure. This applies to both the server operating system and any software you may be running on your website such as a CMS or forum. When security holes are found in software, hackers are quick to attempt to abuse them.

If you are using a managed hosting solution then you don't need to worry so much about applying security updates for the operating system as the hosting company should take care of this.

If you are using third-party software on your website such as a CMS or forum, you should ensure you are quick to apply any security patches. Most vendors have a mailing list or RSS feed detailing any security issues. WordPress, Umbraco and many other CMSes notify you of available system updates when you log in

**4)** *SQL injection* 
 SQL injection attacks are when an attacker uses a web form field or URL parameter to gain access to or manipulate your database. When you use standard Transact SQL it is easy to unknowingly insert rogue code into your query that could be used to change tables, get information and delete data. You can easily prevent this by always using parameterised queries, most web languages have this feature and it is easy to implement.

Comment: Well, I got the best way: USE ".htaccess". Am I right?

Comment: Every website can be hacked. There is no such thing: "ultimate solution". E.g. you can't do anything if someone has physical access to the server.

Comment: @AndrasSebö exactly and this is the thing we need to understand that we can only minimize the risk